# Add line in visudo after root line

Tags: linux, bash, centos, sudo, visudo

I'm testing some Ansible deployment and need to add ansible user to sudoers. Instead of editing I just every time copy this script:

```
echo 'ansible ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
```

Which is adds `ansible ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL` to the end of file.

How to add it after root line to make it like this via script?

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
ansible ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: jww, I think you misunderstood me. The problem is that below script adds line in the end of the file but I need to add line after "root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL" like I showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems a little kludgy, but...

Create a file called add_ansible.sed with the following line:

```
/^root/aansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Then run your visudo like this:

```
sudo EDITOR='sed -i -f add_ansible.sed' visudo
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really have to do it, make it part of the playbook. 
Configuration management should not happen outside the tool to prevent drift.

- template: 
  src: templates/sudoers 
  dest: /etc/sudoers 
  validate: '/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s'